# Terraform Azure Event hub - disable public network access

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, terraform-provider-azure, azure-virtual-network

What is the way we can disable public network access using Terrform for Azure Event Hub

I selected options  public_network_access_enabled as false and public_network_access as false under network_rulesset block and following error

"public_network_access_enabled" is not expected here.

I am not sure what I am missing here...any support would be great help here.

Answer (score 0):

As you say the attribute **public_network_access_enabled** does not exist in the module **azurerm_eventhub**

The attribute **public_network_access_enabled** it is part of the module **azurerm_eventhub_namespace**

> `public_network_access_enabled` - (Optional) Is public network access enabled for the EventHub Namespace? Defaults to true.

Source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventhub_namespace#public_network_access_enabled

### For example:

```
resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "example" {
  name                          = "example-namespace"
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  SKU                           = "Standard"
  capacity                      = 2
  public_network_access_enabled = false # Default is true

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

I am have above configuration  using azurerm_eventhub_namespace and not my provider version is 3.4.0

Comment: The last version of azurerm provider is 3.24. What provider are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Better if you can provide more details about how you have configured the access to your Azure Event Hub Namespace. Because, if you have disabled the public access, you need to enable access via private endpoints. In that case, you need to correctly use `public_network_access_enabled` property in both **namespace** level and **network_rulesets** level.

If you are using **hashicorp** as the provider, check the latest documentations for this in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventhub_namespace#network_rulesets

[Note:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgGuv.png)